# Отключить режим совместимости в IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Как известно, у **IE** есть множество режимов совместимости. И любой сайт может открыться под любой совместимостью.

В моем случае, сайт открывающийся в IE8 с совместимостью IE7 полностью ломается, но в режиме IE8 работает нормально, и в самом IE7 работает нормально.

**Как можно заставить IE не ставить режимы совместимости?**

*Как вообще с этим IE работать, и как его поддерживать...*

Comment: Думаю, что заставить не использовать какие-то режимы будет невозможно. Включаются ведь они ручками юзера. Но я в этом случае, иду от обратного. Наоборот, включаю режим совместимости с самой последней версией осла и верстку адаптирую учитывая это. Когда юзер открывает сайт, то отображается он нормально, а если и захочет переключить совместимость или убрать её, то, как говориться, его личные проблемы.

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обычно использую

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />.
```

Тогда режим совместимости пропадает, но есть ряд [проблем](http://habrahabr.ru/post/201358/).

А так мы поддерживаем только IE9+. Уходите от старых браузеров плз.

Comment: мы уходим :) но для старых браузеров надо хотя-бы красиво отображать надпись "желательно использовать более новый браузер".